# Transcoding a Fast Video (think Snapchat, Instagram)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am very new to the video world, but have noticed social media services.. particular snapchat and instagram do a great job of getting videos to load fast even on poorer connections. I know some of this is how the videos are transcoded.

I have gathered some presets I think I should be using when transcoding with ffmpeg, but am not sure of what formats or other parts of it. I would love to hear what people think!

```
ffmpeg()
    .input(remoteReadStream)
    .outputOptions('-preset fast')
    .outputOptions('-movflags +faststart')
```

Other than that I am not entirely sure what else..

Comment: read further :: https://www.dacast.com/blog/hls-streaming-protocol/

Answer (score 0):

If you want fast start of the video you must ensure that the first frame is key-frame. Use `-force_key_frames '00:00:00.000'` parameter of ffmpeg for such task.

But in fact the main method for fast video response on poor connections is adaptive bitrate streaming (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming). It selects video source with bitrate apropriate for user bandwith. So you need to encode your video in different sizes with different qualities and bitrates and assemble them in special playlist for adaptive streaming.

Comment: I'm not aware of any encoder which does not emit its first output frame as a key-frame. Link?

Comment: It for some reason source file has no key frame at the beginning ffmpeg will skip frames until first key frame. So parameter `-force_key_frames '00:00:00.000'` fixes this issue.

Comment: Sometimes first key frame may dissapear when video frame rate is changed during encoding. For example here is such a problem: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/how-to-force-ffmpeg-to-insert-keyframe-at-first-frame-when-downsampling-a-framer

Comment: That doesn't affect the encoder's output. If first source KF is at 4s, then the first frame the encoder receives is that frame, which will be output as a KF. The decoded process is independent of encoding. The only thing encoder receives is uncompressed frames, where there is no KF status. Share a command which generates output with first frame that is not KF.

Comment: You are wrong about that first 4s will be just skipped. Believe me these frames will be converted in the target video. Unfortunately I have no example file to prove this right now but I’ve faced such problem and it isn’t rare.

Comment: You mentioned the skipping part: *It for some reason source file has no key frame at the beginning ffmpeg will skip frames until first key frame.*

Comment: I mean - skip during playing

Comment: Result video after encoding will have keyframe not at the begin so video will be bogus or begin with significant delay

Comment: That's because of timestamp of first video packet, which is later than first audio packet, not encoder emitting initial non-KF. If you can show the problem with current git head, we would like to hear about it at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: I agree that it is a problem of source video. But mentioned parameter solves it. Also problem with first keyframe appears when source stream is captured from h264 live without encoding, just frame capture. Such video has no keyframe at the beginning and as I can see ffmpeg doesn’t force reencoding if h264 is encoded into another h264. So without additional parameter resulted video will have the same problem at first seconds.

Comment: When streamcopying, force_key_frames has no effect. When encoding, first output frame is a keyframe, so not needed.

Comment: If you want a video keyframe at PTS 0, when first source KF isn't 0 and output muxer is VFR, force `-vsync cfr`